# Syntax error near Source when trying to access a database C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

```
string databaseLocation = "|DataDirectory|\\Users.mdf";
string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + databaseLocation + ";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";    
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = {0}", username);
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.Connection = sqlConnection;
sqlConnection.Open();
int numberOfRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConnection.Close();
return numberOfRows;
```

This should check the Users.mdf database for the number of occorances of the username. but im getting a "syntax error near Source" runtime error when it hits the ExecuteNonQuery. I cant find anything wrong... Please help :)

Comment: It should?  The query returns all rows with a username that matches - you want `SELECT COUNT(*) AS numInstances ...` so you can refer to the column alias to get the value...

Comment: but i thought executenonquery counts the number of results so i dont need the COUNT(*)?

Comment: You are also using String.Format to substitute the user name. Apart from this being a bad idea (you should use command parameters, it will most likely generate a syntax error as the user name in the WHERE clause should be surrounded by single quotes as the username is probably a string column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your formatted sql statement is not including delimiters for the username:

```
command.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = {0}", username);
```

sets the command text to something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = foo
```

This is easily corrected, but it would be better to use a `SqlParameter`:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = @username");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
```

---

Also, `ExecuteNonQuery` will return -1 for the number of rows affected, since the `select` doesn't affect rows.  Instead do:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE Username = @username");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
...
int numberOfRows = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: when I make these changes I get this error: "The data types text and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator."

Comment: @vbman11 Ok, your `Username` column is `Text`.  Change it to an `nvarchar` column of appropriate size.

Comment: @adrift hey nvarchar works! thanks! but what if I want to use a text type?

Comment: @vbman11, `Text` wouldn't be appropriate for a column like this - it was intended to be used for storing text data of up to 2 billion characters.  It is also deprecated (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx).  You could instead use `nvarchar(max)` where it makes sense - not for this column.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be:

```
string databaseLocation = "|DataDirectory|\\Users.mdf";
string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + databaseLocation + ";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";    
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE Username = @User";
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User",username);
command.Connection = sqlConnection;
sqlConnection.Open();
int numberOfRows = command.ExecuteScalar();
sqlConnection.Close();
return numberOfRows;
```